# IsDate Function not recognizing date

Tags: vba

I've got this code

```
   If IsDate(EndTime) = True Then
    Worksheets("Control_File2").Range("D" & lrow2).Value = EndTime
    
    Else
    Worksheets("Control_File2").Range("D" & lrow2).Value = "Not Provided"
    
    End If
```

and currently End Time = "25/08/2021 07:35:47.546" but the code always goes to the "Else" condition.

why is it not recognizing it as a date?

Comment: Because of the `.546`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GSerg pointed out, the milliseconds are not being handled by `IsDate()`.

```
Function IsDate2(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    Rem I added this line to escape empty strings
    If Len(Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
    IsDate2 = IsDate(Split(Value, ".")(0))
End Function
```

Comment: I am trying this now but for some reason now it says that empty cells are dates, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure.  I edited my post to handle the issue.

Comment: Thank you, just one question, when I use the function can I write something like If IsDate2(Start_Time_Value) = True ? I get "ByRef argument type mismatch" and not sure why, am I supposed to have a second parameter for this function?

Comment: @Sam I changed the parameter type to Variant.  This should solve your problem.